# Is this structure a good practice to query for restaurants?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a top collection called categories, inside this collection, there are documents that are my categories, one of those documents is, for example, a restaurant.

That restaurant document has these values:

`name` , `image` and `subcollectionId`

so, when I query to get all my categories from the top collection, I get those attributes for everyone, so, in my other screen, now I can refer to the subcollection of restaurants to get all the restaurants of that category

For example, if I need to get all the restaurants after clicking the restaurant category, I will need to do something like this

```
db.collection("categories").document(restaurantCategoryId).collection(subcollectionId).get()
```

Now, I need to use this query in my other view, to query for all the restaurants inside that category, and I wonder if this schema for doing this is good or it can be done easier

So I decided to do this structure

[image]

Let me know if I need to change something or I doing this in another way

To put more in context, I first query all the categories

```
db.collection("categories").get()
```

Then I display all the categories with its attributes (in this case just name and image) and then in my other view after clicking this category I run this query to get all the restaurants from that category document subcollection

```
db.collection("categories").document(restaurantCategoryId).collection(subcollectionId).get()
```

So, I don't know if I'm wasting reads with this query, or if its a good approach, since I just show to the user all the categories but without all the category list data if they don't click it, after they click that category, I load all the documents from that category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems fine to me -- you're roughly mimicking one the data structures suggested in this video from the official docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data .

you may already be aware, but you have typos in your code -- you need `collection`, not `collect` -- and you'll need to call `.data()` on the result of your query to get the contents

Answer (score 1):

While your schema will definitely work fine, there is also another approach that you might be interested in. You can create a top-level collection named `restaurants` and the corresponding category of the restaurants can be added as a property within the restaurant document, as you can see in the following schema:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- restaurants (collection)
        |
        --- restaurantId (document)
              |
              --- category: "Italian"
              |
              --- //Other properties
```

Now, to get all "Italian" restaurants, you should use the following query:

```
Query italianRestaurants = db.collection("restaurants").whereEqualTo("category", "Italian");
```

To display a list of categories, you might consider adding a document, with a property of type array, where you should simply add all categories of restaurants you have in your app. Your document should look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- data (collection)
        |
        --- restaurant (document)
              |
              --- categories: ["Italian", "French", "Thai"]
```

The benefit of this solution is that you'll always read a single document. This means that you'll always be charged with only a single read operation.

Comment: yes, but this is my use case, I have a bunch of categories, that when I click one of them, lets say pet store, I need to open all the pet stores from that category, so , I store inside top level category the documents with each category pointing to the subcollection whre all pet shops, I use this because in my main fragment, I just want to bring my categories with an image and a text, if I load the entire restaurant with also the categorie, I will need to filter there for just the category with all the restaurant data that the user might not click

Comment: If you have a "bunch of categories", you'll be billed with one read operation for each one of them. What is wrong in filtering all categories? When you filter all restaurants by a category, you get back **only** the restaurants of that particular category and nothing more. I cannot find any issue, do you?

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, you are such a cool dude